# HttpClient or WebClient taking a long time if an invalid domain is supplied

Tags: c#, .net, performance, dns

When fetching data from a domain that does not resolve, it takes more than 10 seconds to go into the catch block.

```
try
{
    var resultDomain = client.GetAsync("http://nonexistent.nonexistent.nonexistent").Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //outputs 
    //The remote name could not be resolved: 'nonexistent.nonexistent.nonexistent'
    //11,0632079
    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message);
    Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
}
```

This while the command

```
nslookup nonexistent.nonexistent.nonexistent
```

finishes almost immediately with the notification that the domain doesnt exist. Is there a way to have the HttpClient/WebClient/... behave as fast as nslookup does? What is .NET waiting for?

According to wireshark, DNS responds immediately

[image]

Comment: Have you tried without `.Result`? (i.e. with `await` instead)

Comment: .Net 5: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tqGqVL

Comment: .Net 4.7.2 (with .Result): couldn't reproduce https://dotnetfiddle.net/6Lmbu8

Comment: At least in dotnetfiddle, 4.7.2 is well below 200ms and .Net 5 is even significantly faster.

Comment: Indeed fiddler does it a lot faster than local. Strange

Comment: Maybe check your dns settings. Does the server have a slow ping?

Comment: It's fast. nslookup also finishes fast

Comment: Hm, ... that's odd ...

Comment: On your local you cannot reproduce either? Just tried in .NET Core latest version with your fiddler. Same result

Comment: Will try in the afternoon.

Comment: From home measured in the .Net 5 version at about 200-300ms. (That's on a 150MBit /15 Cable)

Answer (score -1):

What about setting a timeout lower than the default of 100 seconds?

```
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
client.GetAsync(...);
```